# Kendo Grid-Treeview Drag and Drop Issue

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using a kendo treeview as a drop target for my grid rows.
This code is giving me the following error when the row is dropped in the treeview: Uncaught TypeError: item.level is not a function.

How can I solve this issue?

```
        <%=Html.Kendo().TreeView()
            .Name("treeview")
            .Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes
                .Name("checkedActivities")
                .CheckChildren(true)
            )
            .LoadOnDemand(true)
            .DataTextField("descriptionText")
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Read(read => read.Action("Activity", "Activity"))
                )    
            .DragAndDrop(true)
        %>

        <%: Html.Kendo().Grid<Web.Models.Model>() 
        .Name("grid")
        .BindTo((IEnumerable<Web.Models.Model>)ViewBag.List)
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.PK).Title("PK").Hidden(true);
            columns.Bound(p => p.CODE).Title("Code");
            columns.Bound(p => p.DESCRIPTION).Title("Description");                     
        })       

        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Model(Model => Model.Id(p => p.PK))
        )            
        %>


<script>    
    $("#grid").kendoDraggable({
        filter: "tr",  
        hint: function (element) { 
            return element.clone().css({
                "opacity": 0.6,
                "background-color": "#0cf"
            });
        }
    });

$("#treeview").kendoDropTarget({
    drop: function (e) { 
        console.log("drop");

        var dataSourceGrid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
        var dataSourcetreeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource;

        var draggableElement = e.draggable.currentTarget,                
            dataItem = dataSourceGrid.getByUid(draggableElement.data("uid")); 

        if (dataItem == undefined) {
            dataItem = dataSourcetreeview.getByUid(draggableElement.data("uid")); 
        }

        else {
            dataSourcetreeview.add({ descriptionText: dataItem["DESCRIPTION"] });                                
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do the tree and grid datasources have exactly the same fields?

Comment: @ezanker Code updated. Like you said, the biggest mistake is that I have two different datasources. Solved the issue with the drag and drop from the Grid to the Treeview, now I'm having problem updating my treeview when moving items inside of it. If the dataItem is undefined it means that I'm moving items just in the treeview, from one parent to another one for example. Everything works fine (front-end), but I really don't know how to update my DB.